# <script> src replacement - sandbox breaker - will it last?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, sandbox, xmlhttprequest, script-tag

Hey people, I am working on a web do-dad which allows has an embed code.

In this particular embed, an iframe is added to the page in place of the embed code via javascript.  I now have control of the user's page, and, since I am writing the content of the iframe from javascript as well, control of the iframed page.  Doing this (as opposed to sourcing my iframe from our server) lets us talk to the iframe to do a cool trick.

THE PROBLEM:
the iframed page still needs to ajax stuff from our server.  Sandbox issues!  The solution, it seemed to me was `<script>` src replacement - essentially replacing our ajax procedure with a sandbox-breaker version.

I have been told that this ability of most browsers is on the chopping block.  is this true?  terrible!  I can't find anythign to this effect in my (admittedly brief) research, and though i'd go to the experts

- is `<script>` src replacement a viable mechanism to pull off sandbox-breaker type effects?
- is `<script>` src replacement viable at all?
- how do adwords work?  they need to call home, right?  How do they do that?
- I understand that the soon-to-be available cross site XHR stuff will pop security dialogs - is this true?
- Can anybody recommend and other sandbox breaker technique that won't pop a security dialog?

(yes I am aware of the security concerns - We are wearing protection and whatnot)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> is src replacement a viable mechanism
>   to pull off sandbox-breaker type
>   effects?

Yes

> is src replacement viable at all?

Yes. This was the original AJAX.

> how do adwords work? they need to call
>   home, right? How do they do that?

Adwords are based on a screen-scrape of your site. It is context-related. Ajax content is not scraped unless you know how to use URL hash techniques.

> I understand that the soon-to-be
>   available cross site XHR stuff will
>   pop security dialogs - is this true?

The hosting page would need to explicitly allow this, yes.

> Can anybody reccomend and other
>   sandbox breaker technique that won't
>   pop a security dialog?

Use Flash.

Comment: re adwords: - I am not concerned with it scraping /my/ content. I am wondering what technique it uses to "call home" and get it's ads.